# git push without any issue

Tags: git, github

I have 3 branches on the remote namely

```
* master
* feature1
* feature2
```

on local, I work on feature2 and some other developer work on feature1 he has pushed his changes on the feature 1 and merged it to master.

master is the branch where we keep our final code.
 now I want to push my local changes on to master also but I fear that the changes which are not pulled after the other developer pushed on to master may cause some issue.
what is the best way to achieve all the changes done by him and I should reflect on the master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a completely normal scenario/problem, and the two general ways you would handle this would be to first *merge* `master` into your `feature2` branch, then push, or *rebase* your branch on the remote `master`, and then push.  Something like this:

```
# from feature2
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git push origin feature2

# or, again, from feature2
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push origin feature2
```

You may get merge conflicts from either of the two above options, but again, this is also a normal part of any Git workflow.

Comment: `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be sure nothing breakes `master`, I think you have to introduce an additional branch. Most of the time its called `develop`. You can find more about the `git flow` strategy here: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

There are of course multiple solutions to this problem, but for me this one works just fine.

Hope this helps.